# Help identifying berry (maybe elderberry?)

Tags: plant-identification, tree-identification

I found these berries in my yard, but can’t identify what they are, although they resemble elderberries. They are found in New Jersey in mid-August. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: added an additional photo of the underside of the leaf

[image: berries]
[image: leaves]
[image: bottom of leaf]

Comment: That's not what I know as elder, but I'm on a different continent. Elder had denser clusters of much smaller berries, and different leaves. Can you give an idea of the sizes of the leaves and berries?

Comment: Also the growing environment, and if you can recall, what the flowers were like. I have an idea, but it's not quite right unless the leaves are bigger than they look

Comment: @ChrisH The largest berries are about 1cm wide. The leaves are ~5.5cm wide and 13cm long. I didn’t seem then flowering unfortunately

Comment: Definitely not what I call an elderberry plant here in Canada!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now we know the size of the leaves that's a Cherry Laurel, either [Carolina Laurel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_caroliniana) (leaves look a better match) or  [English Laurel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_laurocerasus).  The fruit will all turn purple in the next few weeks. One  of my sources says "September" but it will vary with climate - yours are well on the way already.

They're not closely related to the true laurels, which include culinary bay. They're named for their resemblance to bay (Laurus nobilis)

**Both are toxic**, leaves, fruit/seeds, even stems according to some reports  I've seen recommendations to handle it with gloves when pruning. The wood is used for firewood, but burning the other parts doesn't sound like it would be a good idea.

Comment: Given that New Jersey seems a bit northernly for Carolina Laurel, [Black Cherry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_serotina) might be a more likely option.

Comment: @bass English laurel would be OK though, and those don't look like any cherry leaves I've seen. They do look a lot like bay leaves, which is how the cherry laurels got their name

Comment: @bass just seen it's a different black cherry. Maybe

Comment: The black cherry possibility made me look at the bottom of the leaf, and it seems to match the description I found (see updated pic in the question)